# mmenujs: take action after panel is opened

Tags: javascript, mmenu

I'd like to take an action after a given panel is opened, like so:

```
sidebar.API.openPanel(document.querySelector("#panel"))
  .then(function)
```

The [documentation](https://mmenujs.com/docs/core/api.html) provides a method for binding to an action:

```
sidebar.API.bind("openPanel:finish", function(panel){
  function()
}
```

But then it's done permanently. I only want to do it once, and there is no 'unbind' method. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable scoped outside the `.bind` function, set it to `true` inside the function and add a check for executing your code only if said variable is `false`

```
let isOpened = false
sidebar.API.bind("openPanel:finish", function(panel){
  if(isOpened === false){ isOpened = true }
  else return

  function(){ // Here is your code that will execute only once }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the bind is still permanent and "hooked" - so even after isOpened is set to true, it'll still execute the function on an opened panel, it just won't repeatedly perform the binding.

Comment: I assumed it was for just one panel. You might need to maintain an array or object of booleans instead of a single variable if there are more than one, and update them likewise

Comment: I would like it to only work for one panel, but the problem recurs here too - the if clause only filters when the binding is set, not when it's executed - whatever the function is, once the binding is set, that function will execute everytime "openPanel:finish" fires